# Is it "a journalist on <newspaper>" or "a journalist of <newspaper>"?

Tags: word-choice

Below is from Assimil:

> I'm a journalist on the "Daily Wail".

Why do we use "on" here? I thought it's "of".

Comment: In AmEng, neither, in my experience. Instead: "I'm a journalist **at** the *Daily Wall*."

Comment: AmE also will sometimes use _from_: "I'm a journalist **from** the _Daily Whale_."

Comment: @Jeff, good point. I would say that's a difference of context: Someone describing where they work would say "at," while someone explaining why they're asking a question would say "from."

Comment: @randomhead - Not necessarily; while I think that the jerk harassing the politician will almost invariably use _from_, I've also frequently heard _from_ when Joe tells Bob what his new job is.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin AmE also uses *with*, including when Joe tells Bob what his new job is: "I'm a journalist **with** the *Daily Whale*."

Comment: @CanadianYankee - Indeed. I'd say (anecdotally) that the querent's two choices, "on" and "of", are vanishingly rare in AmE.

Comment: We really need to clear up about the bit whether it is "Daily Mail", "Daily Wail", or "Daily Whale". My first answer would have been exactly what @randomhead said. But again, Jeff's choice would have hit me hours later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[On](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)** is often used- possibly in the sense of being a member of something (on a jury, on a committee, etc). Here is a typical example:

> He was brought up in Scotland and, after Oxford and six years in the army, he returned there as a journalist on the Glasgow Herald. - *On the roof of the World, Richard Nelsson, 2012*

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=journalist+on+the%2Cjournalist+from+the%2C+journalist+for+the%2C+journalist+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjournalist%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjournalist%20from%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjournalist%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjournalist%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest that **from** and **for** are more widely used, and **with** also makes an appearance. Looking at actual instances, a lot of the **on** references are not relevant whereas most of the **from**, **with** references are. Note that **for** could also be used by a **[stringer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stringer)**. Here are some examples:

> ... a journalist from the Birmingham Gazette pondered upon the meaning of the word 'armistice' - *Voices from the Past, Paul Kendall, 2017*

> Benjamin Wilson, a journalist with “The Eye”, was beaten by police when he refused to give them photographs he had taken of damages at a refugee compound in Monrovia - *Liberia Truth and Reconciliation Commission 2008*

> Consider the following story as told by Heather Ruiz who was a journalist for the Seventh-Day Adventist Church Development Agency (ADRA) - *For the Love of God, Jerry M Ireland, 2017*

Comment: And "journalist for" and "reporter for" are more used than the "from" variants.